# The input parameters of AES encryption / decryption

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher

To my understanding, they are the `S-box`, `Rcon`, plaintext and key. Are there any other inputs?

Comment: Why not include mixing layer components? In any case "input" is a misnomer here. The plaintext and the Sbox don't belong together in such a list but the plaintext and key do.

Answer (score 1):

The "input" parameters for AES (or *any block cipher* for that matter) are the plaintext and a key. The output will then be a ciphertext.

$$ C = E(P, K) = E_k(P) $$

In order to decrypt, you will again need the key, and the ciphertext from the previous step:

$$ P = D(C, K) = D_k(C) $$

The S-box, and Rcon which you are talking about, are steps in the $E$ and $D$ functions; they are usually not considered to be an "input" to the AES cipher.

An S-box (short for substitution box) is a large (reversible) lookup table, in which an input word ([in AES' case, it is a mathematically created lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box)) is mapped to an output word. It is the same in each AES round.

The Rcon function is used in [AES' key schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule).

Both Rcon and the S-box are used in the encryption process, but are not considered "parameters" to the AES cipher; rather think of both as steps in the AES encryption and decryption processes.

**An important note**: something that you *might* consider as an input to the AES encryption/decryption system is a [block mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), and sometimes this mode requires an additional input value; the so called "initialization vector". It is important, for several security reasons, that one uses such a (secure) mode of operation, because any plain block cipher will otherwise trivially leak information.

To sum up: all block ciphers require two (three) inputs: the plaintext, the key(, and the initialization vector).